# Convert Value on Field as New Value to Join as key PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this case, can i do like this ?

Table A:

```
id   |   name  |   trx
1        blue       2
2       yellow      1
3        red        3
```

Table B:

```
id   |   key   | value 
1         a       K1
2         b       K2
3         c       K3
```

then on Table B want the alphabet cast to number as trx on Table A

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

so field "key" on Table B can i join as foreign key with Table A with field "trx" ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Why do you don't join b.id = a.trx? If you are trying to join b.key = a.trx, you need a mapping table for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert single characters to their relative numeric value with the ASCII function.

```
with alpha (letter) as
   ( values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('z') )
select letter || ' = ' || ascii(letter) - ascii('a') + 1
  from alpha;
```

Carefully note however that this works **ONLY** for *single lower case letters*. The corresponding upper case version is "ascii(letter) - ascii('A') + 1".  
Since you really didn't specify any expected results I can only surmise the following join on the tables/data given:

```
with Table_A (id,name,trx) as
   ( values (1,'blue',2)
          , (2,'yellow',1)
          , (3,'red ',3)
    )
   , Table_B (id,key,value) as 
   ( values (1,'a','K1')
          , (2,'b','K2')
    )
select a.name,b.value
  from table_a a
  join table_b b
    on (ascii(b.key) - ascii('a') + 1) = a.id;
```